# badblocks and mkfs.ext4

Tags: badblocks, mkfs

I've ran `badblocks` on a disk `/dev/sdc` and now I want to use the saved file with badblocks as an argument to `mkfs.ext4 -l` on a partition.

Block size used in both commands are the same. But I'm formating a partition which is not the first one of the disk.

Should block numbers be recalculated and if yes, how to do it?

I do not want to run `mkfs.ext4 -c` as that will take more time.

Answer (score 0):

> Should block numbers be recalculated and if yes, how to do it?

Rerun badblocks on this partition alone or you actually need to recalculate everything and I'm not sure how it can be done - this must be relatively easy but you can easily make a mistake.

Lastly if your drive has failing blocks, I wouldn't use it for anything at all.

Comment: You don't need to rerun badblocks. You just need to add the sector offset.

Comment: Should I add the partition start to the saved list? What is the safest way to get it?

Comment: @forest Can you offer a readily available script to do that? My answer, while not optimal, will work regardless.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I don't have a script, but it should be pretty trivial to do with a one-liner.

Comment: OK, great, downvoting is always easier than writing and testing a script. I get it.